# ScrollView.FOCUS_UP not working in my project with root layout as scrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I know it is silly question but i used many solution which already given by stack Overflow but no one solve my problem, my question is, I want to Scroll Up the layout after clicking on last edittext because keyboard hide the EditText and i am unable to see what is typing..

Code I am using in onCreate method

```
    scrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
    addressEdt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.profilAddress);

        addressEdt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
                    }
                });
```

My xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Kevin Michaels"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_rides_editProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textSize="17dp" />

                <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userProfileImageView"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_user_icon" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/profileImageProgress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userChangePhotoButton"
                    android:layout_width="37dp"
                    android:layout_height="37dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout7">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                style="@style/ProfileUserNameEditText"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/txtprofileUserName"/>

            <EditText
                style="@style/ProfileMobileNumberEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/profileMobile"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Mobile"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="phone|textPhonetic"/>

            <EditText
                style="@style/ProfileAddressEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/profilAddress"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/edit_profile_address"
                android:maxLength="40"
                />

            <TextView
                style="@style/ProfileEmailEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/profileEmail"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/saveProfileButton"
                android:background="@drawable/a_log_in_button"
                android:text="Done"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="17dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```